# C++ Command line program unwantedly pauses on Windows 8. How to prevent?

Tags: c++, windows

I have written a C++ CMD program to do a numerically intensive simulation, which takes about 1 hour to run on my Laptop with an i7 processor on Windows 8. 
The program prints a status update to the command line about every 5 seconds.

But from time to time, the programs suddenly pauses and does not resume until I click the cursor into the CMD window and hit Enter.
While the program pauses the CPU load, displayed in the taskmanager, also drops to almos 0% (instead of the ~17%).

My program does at no point during the simulation ask for user input. 
I assume that for some reason the operating system pauses execution of my program.
My Laptop is connected to the powersupply and all energy saving options are currently disabled.

This behaviour does not always happen, even with the very same program just being restarted.

**How do I prevent this unwanted pause?**

Could anyone please give me a tip, where I could start searching?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior while running under a debugger?  If so, instead of clicking into the window use the debugger to break into the program and see what it's doing.

Comment: Do you have **"QuickEdit" mode** turned on for your command prompt window? Right-click on the title bar, select Properties, look on the first tab.

Comment: What Cody Gray is asking for: If you click on the cmd window with the mouse your program will be paused. This is by design to allow to check the cmd output of an busy application. Could it be that you from time to time by accident pause your own program?

Comment: Cody Gray and Alois Kraus were absolutely correct.
I did (when switching to the program that was running in the background) from time to time accidently pause my own program by clicking into it.
Thank you for the answer and please excuse my late reply.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect if you redirect your program's output to file, all will be good.

In other words, instead of typing this at the command prompt:

```
d:\MyAppDirectory>  myprogram.exe
```

Type this instead:

```
d:\MyAppDirectory>  myprogram.exe > output.txt
```

The above will place all of your program's output into the output.txt file.

If you need to monitor the program's output in real time, you can probably find a "tail" program for Windows to run in a seperate window.  ala `tail output.txt` while your main program is running (Google for "tail for windows")

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along the lines of:

```
DWORD mode = PIPE_NOWAIT;
SetNamedPipeHandleState(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &mode, NULL, NULL);
```

at the beginning of your program. However, this assumes that there isn't an actual bug in your program and you aren't waiting for input yourself.